# Differencing Disks in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, diskmanagement, diff

I'm struggling to understand how to do differencing disks in VirtualBox v3.1.0. I've created a Windows 2008 Server, but now I want to use that as a base image for a number of other servers. The help file has a description of what differencing disks are, but I can't find where it actually tells you how to do it. In the Storage dialog for a server I found the Differencing Disks checkbox:
[alt text http://www.philippursglove.com/stackoverflow/virtualbox%20differencing%20disks.png](http://www.philippursglove.com/stackoverflow/virtualbox%20differencing%20disks.png)
but when I check it, I'd expect it to then ask which image should be the parent so I could select my base image.

Any pointers you can offer would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disconnect and remove VHD from VirtualBox and then register it with a command line:

VBoxManage openmedium disk  -type immutable

After you attach it to a virtual machine, VirtualBox will automaticly create a differencing disk.

Now it beats me, how to create a chained differncing disk from that one?, 
To have for eg. W2008 -> W2008+SQL2008 -> W2008+SQL2008+SharePoint?